# Rails redirect with variable in https address

Tags: ruby, redirect, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i am trying from within a controller to redirect to an IP address that contains a variable [params[:uid]] but i cant get it to evaluate properly. I am trying:

```
redirect_to "https://www.yooooos.com/RemLite/Displaystudy.HTML?studyUIDsList= params[:uid]&username=usrrrrr&password=raanndke"
```

the address is valid but server connection resets when i try it.  what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot about #{}

Try this:

```
redirect_to "https://www.yooooos.com/RemLite/Displaystudy.HTML?studyUIDsList=#{params[:uid]}&username=usrrrrr&password=raanndke"
```